# Partially sorting array so last n elements are sorted?

Tags: c++, sorting, standard-library

Is there a way to perform a partial sort on an array of data so that the last n elements are sorted? By good I mean using the standard library, not implementing my own sort function (this is what I'm doing right now).
Example output (using less comparator):

> 2 1 4 || 5 6 8 10

Elements after `||` are all greater than elements than elements before `||`, but only elements to the right of `||` (indices closer to the end of the array) are guaranteed to be sorted.

This is basically a reversal of the std::partial_sort function which sorts the left (first) elements.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Use `std::partial_sort` with reverse iterators.

For example:

```
int x[20];
std::iota(std::begin(x), std::end(x), 0);
std::random_shuffle(std::begin(x), std::end(x));

std::reverse_iterator<int*> b(std::end(x)),
                            e(std::begin(x));
std::partial_sort(b, b+10, e, std::greater<int>());
for (auto i : x)
    std::cout << i << ' ';
```

Comment: I think it needs a different comperator as well, so add `std::greater` to the mix.

Answer (score 7):

Another possibility instead of `partial_sort` with reverse iterators and std::greater for the comparison would be to use `std::nth_element` to partition the collection, then std::sort to sort the partition you care about:

```
std::vector<int> data{5, 2, 1, 6, 4, 8, 10}; //  your data, shuffled

std::nth_element(data.begin(), data.begin()+2, data.end());

std::sort(data.begin()+2, data.end();
```

Comment: out of curiosity, are there any reasons/cases I would considering using this solution instead of reverse iterators?

Comment: @helloworld922: I can see two. The first is that (at least to me) it simply seems a lot more readable. The second is that in most cases we can expect it to be more efficient. With N = overall size and M = size to sort, partial_sort has complexity ~O(N log M), where this has complexity ~O(N + M log M).

Comment: hmm, interesting. Funny that they wouldn't implement partial sort internally like this if it's potentially faster.

Comment: @helloworld922: They could, of course -- I'm only quoting what the standard requires them to do.

Comment: I'm not sure you can say that in most cases we can expect it to be more efficient.  You have to consider what are the common use cases of a partial sort.  Based on no data, just intuition, I would have to guess that the primary use case for partial sort is when you have a large amount of data N, but you want to find the top M items, where M is much smaller than N.  Because as M approaches N, you get to the point where you might as well just do a full sort.  And in those cases, from my tests, partial_sort beats nth_element+sort, standard complexity guarantees be damned.

Comment: @BenjaminLindley: You're probably right: "most cases" is probably overstating the situation at least a little.

Comment: The question states, "Elements after || [in the result] are all greater than elements before ||". I'm not sure this is what your answer is doing.

Comment: @WillNess: Yes, it is. Along with finding the nth-element, std::nth_element partitions the collection, so smaller elements are arranged before it and the larger elements after it.

Comment: @JerryCoffin thanks for clarifying! Totally unexpected, judging just from its name. "`nth_smallest`" could be a clearer name for that function.

Answer (score 0):

Using ranges and views in c++20 it is quite simple.

**Array example:**

```
//DATA
int arrayOfInts[8] = { 82,80,81,86,83,85,84,88 };

//SORT LAST 5 ELEMENTS. SO DROP FIRST 3.
std::ranges::sort(std::views::drop(arrayOfInts, 3));

//PRINT ARRAY -- 82  80  81 || 83  84  85  86  88
for (auto i : arrayOfInts)
    std::cout << i << "  ";
```

**Vector example:**

```
//DATA
std::vector<int> vecOfInts = { 82,80,81,86,83,85,84,88 };

//SORT LAST 5 ELEMENTS. SO DROP FIRST 3.
std::ranges::sort(std::views::drop(vecOfInts, 3));

//PRINT VECTOR -- 82  80  81  || 83  84  85  86  88
for (auto i : vecOfInts)
    std::cout << i << "  ";
```

Comment: The question states, "Elements after || [in the result] are all greater than elements before ||". Now look at your example output. Where is 86?

Comment: Ok. I will change the example. Anyhow that won't be a problem as conceptually we are dropping the elements from the view.

Comment: No, you shouldn't make it look like it's working when in fact it isn't working properly, like your original example had demonstrated.