# Complexity of partial_sort vs nth_element

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

According to cppreference.com, the complexity of the C++ STL sorting algorithms is:

`sort`: O(N log(N))

`partial_sort`: "approximately" O(N log(M)), where M is distance(middle-first)

`nth_element`: "on average" O(N)

However, this seems to imply that, instead of doing a `partial_sort`, you could use `nth_element` and then sort the first range, to give an overall complexity of O(N + M log(M)), which is a bit better than O(N log(M)). Is this actually true? Am I better off avoiding `partial_sort`?

Comment: order of complexity matters when the size of input the big. For small inputs, I don't think it will matter that much

Comment: Very interesting question. See Benjamin Lindley's comment to the last answer [in this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14348602/partially-sorting-array-so-last-n-elements-are-sorted) - he says that, empirically, it's faster for some cases.

Comment: Quickselect has a large constant factor, so I guess this only makes sense for rather large M. Benchmarking with some of your real inputs will tell

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After extensive testing, it seems that `partial_sort` is faster for my use-case. I suspected as much -- but this seems to confirm it.

Answer (score 27):

`std::partial_sort` would perform partial sort for the M elements you are interested in. On the other hand `std::nth_element` would only give you an array, such that nth element is placed such that all elements on the left are smaller and on the right are greater.

Use `std::partial_sort` for use cases such as, getting top 10 results out of a million in order of rank. Use `std::nth_element` for finding the median of an array, or to find out who stood 10th in exam results.

If you are just interested in the performance characteristics of both, for smaller values of M, `std::partial_sort` would perform better than `std::nth_element` (about 10,000) . For a detailed analysis of this, see: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-0tO3Eni2uo

## Summary of video

`std::nth_element` uses modified Quickselect, which provides O(N) complexity regardless of M.

`std::partial_sort` uses Heapselect, which provides better performance than Quickselect for small M. As a side effect, the end state of Heapselect leaves you with a heap, which means that you get the first half of the Heapsort algorithm "for free".

`std::partial_sort` is optimized for the case where M is a small constant relative to N. For example, taking the top 10 items from a very large variable-length list. It is not optimized for the other cases.

In a race between `std::partial_sort` and `std::nth_element` + `std::sort`, `std::partial_sort` jumps out to an early lead (small M) but is overtaken by `std::nth_element` + `std::sort` once M is no longer small.

Comment: Downvote is not mine but you can improve your answer by summing up the youtube video. Answers should be self contained whenever possible